# Is there a simple funtion to atomatically reduce stock levels when product is added to cart? - Woo

Tags: woocommerce, stock

I need a solution that reduces the stock level and hide the product from others directly when the product is added to the cart. I have set stock amount to 1 and only allow one purchase of each product.

I´ve tried plugins like WooCommerce Cart Stock Reducer, it does the trick but doesnt hide the product instead it gives me a message that its out of stock.

Help anyone?

Comment: So basically You want to hide the product when out of stock.?

Answer (score 0):

From the left side panel in your admin, go to `WooCommerce->Settings->Products->Inventory`
then check the `Hide out of stock items from the catalog` option.

You should be good.